# android emulation on virtual box in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, virtualbox

I have android running on virtualbox, to use it as a second cell phone with an bluetooth usb stick, to connect it with a real device.

I have 2 Questions:

1. Is it possible to get access with DDMS in eclipse like the real device to the virtual box version?
2. How can i install in .apk package on the virtual box android?

I hope somoeone can help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

1. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, type `netcfg` write down the IP address and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>.
2. Run `adb connect <virtual_machine_ip>` in terminal on your host machine.

You should then see the device in ADT and be able to run your applications on it.

**Edit:** This will work if you are set up to use bridged or host-only adapters: for NAT you must set up port forwarding first:

1. cd to your VirtualBox folder on Windows: (C:/Program Files/Oracle/VirtualBox)
2. set up a port forwarding rule via command line like so: `VBoxManage modifyvm <name_of_your_android_vm> --natpf1 adb,tcp,*,5555,*,5555`
3. Run your vm
4. Connect to your VM by typing `adb connect localhost:5555`
5. Launch your application in Eclipse and you will see localhost:5555 as an available AVD

Comment: adb says: unable to connect! Whats the port, is standard 5555 right? the ip, which if have to use of netcfg is eth0, right?

Comment: i edit my post, sorry! what do you mean with permissions? I only write ./adb.exe <the right ip> in the right folder in command line

Comment: is it possible to access the virtualbox with ADT not using command line?

Comment: Im not sure why it won't connect. I followed these steps and it worked for me... I didnt need to specify a port either.

Comment: maybe a problem with network connection on Virtual box, i use NAS and have internet access. Should i change something? The ip adress is 10.0.2.15 does this sound ok to you? Maybe some useful info: it really needs time until he comes up with the unable connect message, 20 seconds i guess.

Comment: do i need port forewarding in virtual box and if so, how do i create the rule?

Comment: works! but the usb connection with the real device in eclipse is lost! idea?

Comment: I usually don't have an AVD running while having a device connected via USB, confuses things... you can mark this answer as accepted by clicking on the check mark.

Comment: So can we debug the Android Project in Eclipse using VirtualBox of Android ??