# How to decrease Eclipse AVD Load Time?

Tags: android, eclipse

I am working on an android application, uing eclipse IDE. However it takes around **10-15 minutes to load my AVD** and run the application.

***My system Configuration: 
RAM 8GB
intel Core2Duo Processor 2.53GHz.
OS:  windows 7***

Is their any alternative to increase our AVD's speed, without changing my systems hardware configurations.

Comment: simplest way would be to buy a faster computer. On a more serious note, SO isn't really the place for this

Comment: Can we allocation some sort of virtual memory to eclipse IDE or AVD .. to improve its performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can setup an Android Virtual Machine using VirtualBox :

http://www.howtogeek.com/164570/how-to-install-android-in-virtualbox/

And to deploy to the virtual box :

[android emulation on virtual box in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751911/android-emulation-on-virtual-box-in-eclipse)

I tried this a while back and it was quite a performance improvement difference. I haven't done this in a while because I bought a pretty high end phone and I just use that now.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, solution work pretty well for me.

Comment: No problems, made a massive difference for me when testing openGL applications primarily.

Answer (score 0):

> Is their any alternative to increase our AVD's speed

Using [the x86 emulator](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#accel-vm) will help.

That being said, your computer would appear to have issues. With that configuration, even the ARM emulator should take at most a minute or two, at least on Linux. Windows 7 perhaps adds some more overhead, but I would not expect it to be that much.

Also, bear in mind that you can usually keep your emulator open all day -- you do not have to exit and restart the emulator for most work.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I am working on x86 emulator only, with ARM it takes more time .. to work with Intel x86 emulator, do I need to install any driver software or simply selecting Intel x86 emulator from the Drop Down list will work.

Comment: @PulkitGupta: You need to follow the instructions for installing HAXM, as is outlined in the documentation that I linked to. Also, you need to download the x86 emulator images for the various Android OS levels you want to emulate. Then, you will be able to choose x86 in the "CPU/ABI" drop-down in the AVD editor.

Answer (score 0):

GenyMotion have an Android Emulator that is pretty rapid. (not an AVD)

http://www.genymotion.com/

> Genymotion is an emulator using x86 architecture virtualization,
>   making it much more efficient!
>
> Taking advantage of OpenGL hardware acceleration, it allows you to
>   test your applications with amazing 3D performance.

It's free for personal use, has preconfigured devices (like N7 or Samsung GS3 etc).

I think you'll really like it.

Answer (score 0):

You can select the snapshot options. On the first next start, a snapshot will be created. This will improve the launch speed of the emulator every other start...

[image]